# How do I block callers from leaving voicemails?

Tags: iphone, privacy, call, voicemail

A scammer has been harassing me for several days, being rude and making fraudulent claims. How can I stop them from calling me?

Comment: You’ll need a lawyer to help with fraud claims, but the iOS block should help in the mean time if you don’t decide to pursue action through your wireless carrier.

Answer (score 4):

In your Phone app → Recents, tap the ⓘ next to the phone number you wish to block, then tap **Block this Call** at the very bottom.

You can also tap the ⓘ next to an undesirable voicemail message under Phone → Voicemail.

[image]

[image]

Blocked callers can still leave you voicemails, but they will go straight into a separate **Blocked Messages** voice mailbox without raising a notification or ringtone. You’ll never have to listen to them.

You may also try downloading some call-filtering apps from the App Store. Free ones include Whoscall, Truecaller, and Hiya. They use Apple’s CallKit to proactively block known spammers and scammers. I am not affiliated with any of those apps.

AT&T also offers AT&T Call Protect for its own customers, also on the App Store. Other carriers have their own offerings as well.

Comment: You are 100% correct - the cellular carrier is the one entity that’s best placed to stop this. They sell service to end users and could easily enforce traceable calls - allowing consumers to be sure they know who is calling if a call goes through. The carriers not implementing this sort of consumer friendly service makes me think they profit more by allowing unwanted calls than it costs them to service their paying customers.

Comment: You couldn’t be more right. AT&T Call Protect was entirely free up until last week. Now only the basic service is free, with more advanced spam filtering options coming in as a subscription service, costing $3.99/month 